# Add two button to page and post admin to redirect to : add new & list of (posts - pages) just after saving post or page

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, admin, buttons

I would like to add some extra button inside post and admin page creating plugin or adding hook inside functions.php.
The image below resume all I want :

(1) depending to we are on wordpress post or page .
Two buttons next to Update or Save (post or page (1)) button.
First one allow to add a new (Post or page (1)) just after saving or updating the current.
The second allow to go back to list (Post or page *) just after saving or updating the current.

[image: previewaddbuttonadmin]

Comment: Can you show what you have - in terms of code - so far, what errors you have, define specific problem points - the question now is far too general to have a specific answer.

Comment: I don't have yet code , I collect the information :
Is it possible to add these buttons at this position (left to the update/publish button) ? 
Must I used "post_row_actions" filter ?
I see this solution : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/315994/how-to-after-saving-or-publishing-a-post-redirect-back-to-the-original-page.
And this codex : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_row_actions/ .
Is it enough to make my buttons?

Comment: It's better that you try first, then ask about specific problems.

Comment: I understand and it' normal, but how I know if Wordpress allow this hook ? does exist a map/design that show all possible hook inside post edit page ?

Comment: Perhaps this: https://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook

Comment: Only Elementor managed to add a custom button inside header of gunthenberg editor : https://github.com/elementor/elementor/blob/master/assets/dev/js/admin/gutenberg.js
I won't be able to reuse that code and do what I want. 
I have tried to use that code : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67154/add-button-to-post-edit-page-when-post-status-publish/67163 ,  but it seems that post_submitbox_misc_actions is not working anymore : https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/12764